# Animated square bouncing inside of a box. Filling the square with an image. Working with [canvas] [img] fillStyle and drawImage()

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawimage

Took me a while, but I finally figured out how to get an image to appear to bounce inside of a box. The solution involves drawImage(). Initially, I thought that the default black color of the box was preventing my selected image. It's better to use the drawImage() method, which can take as many as 5 arguments and as few as 3.

```
<body>
    <canvas width="400" height="400" style="background: orange"> 
        </canvas>
    <img id="bob" src="./bpTransB.png" alt="bobPig" 
          style="visibility: hidden">

<script>
  const cx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
  var img = document.getElementById("bob");

  var lastTime = null;
  function frame(time) {
    if (lastTime != null)
      updateAnimation(Math.min(100, time - lastTime) / 1000);
    lastTime = time;
    requestAnimationFrame(frame);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(frame);

  var x = 100, y = 60, width = 20, height = 20, speedX = 100, speedY = 60;

  function updateAnimation(step) {
    // draws the blue box (comment cx.clearRect() back in to clear contrail)
    // cx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
    cx.strokeStyle = "blue";
    cx.lineWidth = 4;
    cx.strokeRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
    // handles the change of direction in the animation
    x += step * speedX;
    y += step * speedY;
    if (x < width - 35 || x > 373 - width)
      speedX = -speedX;
    if (y < height - 25 || y > 373 - height)
      speedY = -speedY;
    // draws the image on the canvas 
    cx.drawImage(img, x, y, 65, 55);
    cx.beginPath();   
    cx.fill();
  }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: sorry, where is the question? if you solve you own problem, either post an answer, or delete your question _Do not_ edit your post to something that isn't a question anymore.

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks for the comment. The question: How to replace an animated bouncing square (like in an old 2d video game) with an image, so that the image bounced inside a box.  I kept getting the default color (black), instead of the image I wanted to use.  I learned that drawImage() solved my problem.  Let me know if you want more details.  I'm glad to share.

Comment: No, not as a comment: it seems you maybe forgot to take the [tour] and read through the ["how to ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask) policy article and update your post accordingly. As is, this is absolutely not the kind of post that belongs on Stackoverflow in its current form. And also remember to read ["what is on-topic"](/help/on-topic) just to make sure you don't end up editing it to a form that is clearly something that SO is not intended for.

Comment: Again, thanks for the comments Mike.  I think I'll leave my first SO not-quite-a-question up for the benefit of other newbies to programming.  I read your profile and see that you're an experienced software engineer, which is far beyond my current skill level.  If I post again and solve my own problem, I'll leave the original question up and post the answer, as you advised.

Comment: Yeah, so: please follow the SO policies rather than making up your own policy and forcing that onto a site. In the 20 hours since your comment, you haven't updated it, and this question already has three close votes, so the fact that _your post is not a question_ means it _has no benefits_ to newbies. What does have value is having a question post, and then one or more answer posts. (which is literally the thing we ask you to do, because that's how SO works: it's a Q&A website)